# MySQL memory requirement

Tags: mysql

I have scenarios like below:

1. Database with single table (innodb storage engine)
2. This table is ~350GB including table & index.
3. Table size ~250GB
4. Index Size ~110GB
5. Table is partitioned and size of partition ranges from 1G to 10G
6. Table contains 3 indexes.
7. One is primary (with non-auto increment column ).
8. Rest two index is non-unique
9. No other application is running on this server.
10. Server is having 128 GB of RAM
11. Our Query is hitting one partition at one point.
12. Multiple such queries can hit for different partitions.

I just learned that I would need 1.15 times innodb buffer.  I am running "**mysqltuner.pl**" and it is recommending me for ~417GB of innodb buffer size.  I don't know why it is recommending so much of memory for DB.

Would anybody come up with suggestion on the size of INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE.

Regards,
Sanjeeva

Comment: check: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27328/how-large-should-be-mysql-innodb-buffer-pool-size

Comment: Hi My ratio as per formula in this link gives "**99.7916**".  Further, with buffer calculation formula I am getting more or less same recommendation as with "**mysqltuner.pl**".  Is there any explanation found for such a huge (in my case) memory requirement?  Is this much of memory required because MySQL place index+ tabledata both into memory while first time hit by query on the table?

Comment: Hi thisissanjeeva.com, please let us know what your workflow looks like, do you have primarily selects, inserts, deletes and/or updates? It is crucial to know that in order to suggest a meaningful buffer pool size. Also is there a certain task which is not performing well enough with the current setup?

Comment: We ran "replace" and select only.